# How to implement bson producer/consumer for resteasy

Tags: java, jax-rs, resteasy, bson

We're developing a service that uses the resteasy framework. It works fine with XML and json application/content-types. However, we need to use one more format: bson.

I installed the bson4jackson plugin, but I can't figure out how I should use it with resteasy. I understand that I have to implement a producer/consumer class, but I didn't find any examples.

Any advices/ideas to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement a custom `MessageBodyReader` and `MessageBodyWriter` to handle the bson media type.

**Reader:**

```
@Provider
@Consumes("application/bson")
public class BsonMessageBodyReader implements MessageBodyReader {

}
```

**Writer:**

```
@Provider
@Produces("application/bson")
public class BsonMessageBodyWriter implements MessageBodyWriter {

}
```